# Delegate administration rights to OU in OpenLDAP?

Tags: openldap

How would I allow a user to administer subordinates of only a single OU in an OpenLDAP directory? The goal here is I want the user to be able to create and update users under a specific OU only.

I sure miss Active Directory... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using OpenLDAP [Access Control Lists](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html). You need to put to your `slapd.conf` a new line similar to this under to that specific OU's slapd.conf entry:

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=yourou,dc=yourdomain,dc=com"
by dn.exact="cn=youradministratoruser,ou=yourou,dc=yourdomain,dc=com"
(other ACL rules go here)
```

Comment: I am dealing with this exact problem as well, but trying to get it managed by a group, instead of a user.. IE, cn=LocalIT,ou=yourou,dc=ourdomain,dc=com"  What is the syntax to use for "any member of group LocalIT"?

Comment: @Brian: See section `8.4.4. Managing access with groups` from here: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html ... `group.exact` is the keyword you are looking for, but the tutorial has some more details for you, too.