# How to allow users on an openLDAP server to create, update, and modify users under a certain organizationalUnit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I have been stuck on trying to allow openLDAP users that are in a certain group (EX: `cn=Admins,dc=mydomain,dc=com`) to `create, modify, update, and delete` users that are in another `organizationalUnit` (EX: `ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com`) for about two weeks now. I have done everything in my power to try to figure this out. Such as searching through Google, searching through [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), and finally searching through [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) but to no avail. I am fairly new to openLDAP and it is probably an error and/or something that I am overlooking with the `olcAccess` attribute in the `dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config`.

**Admin Group.ldif**

```
dn: cn=Admins,dc=ldapserver,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
member: cn=admin,ou=Users,dc=ldapserver,dc=com
cn: Admins
```

**Users.ldif**

```
dn: ou=Users,dc=ldapserver,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Users
```

**Default olcAccess**

**Note:** This is the default ACLs that come with a fresh install of openLDAP server.

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by * read
```

**Please Note 1:** Because I am fairly new to openLDAP I have not set any other `ACLs` other than the ones that come defaultly when you first install the openLDAP server.

**Please Note 2:** Before I Asked my question I tried this question [here](https://serverfault.com/a/406471/305162) which obviously has not worked for me.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: The OpenLDAP documentation on ACLs is quite comprehensive, albeit not a short read by all means. Having said that, it's worth checking out. There are plenty of examples that may come in handy. http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html

Comment: @Rouben I have read the documentation already but there was no good answer to my question.

Comment: @Rouben There was an answer that allowed a certain group of people to change passwords of other users which can be found [here](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) and search for `8.4.4. Managing access with Groups`.

Comment: So would something like this work? `access to dn.regex="(.+,)?ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com$" by group.exact="cn=Admins,dc=mydomain,dc=com" manage` By the way, the "Admins" group should be a cn not an ou. An OU is meant to contain objects (like users or groups), and a group is an object. If you have Admins set up as an OU, then you probably need to match it differently... `by group.regex="(.+,)?ou=Admins,dc=mydomain,dc=com$"` These are untested, by the way, and I admit that I am no LDAP expert... Just trying to make sense of the documentation. :)

Comment: The first regex matches everything in the `Users` OU, the second regex (assuming syntax is right, I made it up) matches everything in the `Admins` OU.

Comment: @Rouben I followed the ACL and I got `error code 50 - no write access to parent`. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It would appear that granting access to members of the OU is insufficient... http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200902/msg00083.html So my guess is you also have to grant access to the OU itself. Maybe something like this? `access to dn.subtree=ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com` as the first line of the ACL command? Just keep in mind I am not an expert at this!!! Take my advice with a grain of salt! :)

Comment: @Rouben Still got the exact same error as before.

Comment: Sorry @Alex not sure what else to try...

Comment: @Rouben I guess I will keep on looking until I get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ACLs, in openldap, is always evaluated from top to bottom of the list of lines numbered {0}, {1},..As soon as a condition is met, evaluation is **immediately** stopped (assuming break not used).

In default ACLs set by Ubuntu and compliant there is the line:

olcAccess: {2}**to *** by * read

to * by *: met everything, adding lines after has no effect at all.

The solution discussed on [this link](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200902/msg00083.html) and above should solve your problem, I suggest you try this ACL list:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: {2}to dn.subtree="ou=Users,dc=ldapserver,dc=com"
             by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=Admins,dc=ldapserver,dc=com" write
```

and change the objectClass of the admins group to groupOfUniqueNames.

Comment: And probably add `olcAccess: {3}to * by * read`